# What is the size limit for JsonItemExporter in Scrapy?

Tags: scrapy

The following warning is mentioned in the [Feed Exports section](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html#) of Scrapy docs.

From the docs for `JsonItemExporter`:

> JSON is very simple and flexible serialization format, but it doesn’t scale well for large amounts of data since incremental (aka. stream-mode) parsing is not well supported (if at all) among JSON parsers (on any language), and most of them just parse the entire object in memory. If you want the power and simplicity of JSON with a more stream-friendly format, consider using JsonLinesItemExporter instead, or splitting the output in multiple chunks.

Does this mean that the `JsonItemExporter` is not suitable for incremental (aka stream data) or does it also imply a size limit for `json`?

If this means that this exporter is not suitable also for large files, does anyone have a clue about the upper limit for `json` items / file size (for e.g. 10MB or 50MB)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JsonItemExporter does not have a size limit. The only Limitation remains to be no support for streamable objects.